# Can this be achieved on Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I am trying to make my `JFrame` appear next to my dock on Mac OSX using the following code but it doesn't work. Is it even possible to do make a frame appear there? I am using Java.

```
frame.setLocation(5, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height-45);
```

Here is what I always get:
[image]

And here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to make use of the `GraphicsDevice`, `GraphicsEnvironment` and `GraphicsConfiguration` APIs

`Toolkit#getScreenSize` does just that, it returns the size of the screen, but it doesn't include all the OS elements, like the dock, which take up additional space

[image: Sitting upon the dock]

So, this is a bunch of library code, designed to find the `GraphicsDevice` a particular component resides on, or, the default `GraphicsDevice` ... library code ;)

```
public static Rectangle getDefaultScreenBounds() {
    return getScreenBounds(null, true);
}

public static Rectangle getScreenBounds(Component comp, boolean acceptDefault) {
    Rectangle bounds = getScreenBounds(comp);
    if ((bounds == null || (bounds.x == 0 && bounds.y == 0 && bounds.width == 0 && bounds.height == 0)) && acceptDefault) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    }
    return bounds;
}

public static Rectangle getScreenBounds(Component comp) {
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDevice(comp);

    if (gd != null) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        bounds = gc.getBounds();
    }
    return bounds;
}

public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDevice(Component comp) {
    GraphicsDevice device = null;
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
    List<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<>(lstGDs.length);
    if (comp != null && comp.isVisible()) {
        Rectangle parentBounds = comp.getBounds();
        /*
         * If the component is not a window, we need to find its location on the
         * screen...
         */
        if (!(comp instanceof Window)) {
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, comp);
            parentBounds.setLocation(p);
        }

        for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
            if (screenBounds.intersects(parentBounds)) {
                lstDevices.add(gd);
            }
        }
        if (lstDevices.size() == 1) {
            device = lstDevices.get(0);
        } else {
            GraphicsDevice gdMost = null;
            float maxArea = 0;

            for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstDevices) {
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

                Rectangle2D intBounds = bounds.createIntersection(parentBounds);
                float perArea = (float) ((intBounds.getWidth() * intBounds.getHeight()) / (parentBounds.width * parentBounds.height));
                if (perArea > maxArea) {
                    maxArea = perArea;
                    gdMost = gd;
                }
            }
            if (gdMost != null) {
                device = gdMost;
            }
        }
    }

    return device;
}
```

And, this is how you might use it...

```
package javaapplication1.pkg169;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                Rectangle bounds = getDefaultScreenBounds();
                System.out.println(bounds);
                int x = bounds.x + ((bounds.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
                frame.setLocation(x, bounds.y + (bounds.height - frame.getHeight()));
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static Rectangle getDefaultScreenBounds() {
        return getScreenBounds(null, true);
    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenBounds(Component comp, boolean acceptDefault) {
        Rectangle bounds = getScreenBounds(comp);
        if ((bounds == null || (bounds.x == 0 && bounds.y == 0 && bounds.width == 0 && bounds.height == 0)) && acceptDefault) {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        }
        return bounds;
    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenBounds(Component comp) {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDevice(comp);

        if (gd != null) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            bounds = gc.getBounds();
        }
        return bounds;
    }

    public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDevice(Component comp) {
        GraphicsDevice device = null;
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
        List<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<>(lstGDs.length);
        if (comp != null && comp.isVisible()) {
            Rectangle parentBounds = comp.getBounds();
            /*
             * If the component is not a window, we need to find its location on the
             * screen...
             */
            if (!(comp instanceof Window)) {
                Point p = new Point(0, 0);
                SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, comp);
                parentBounds.setLocation(p);
            }

            for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
                if (screenBounds.intersects(parentBounds)) {
                    lstDevices.add(gd);
                }
            }
            if (lstDevices.size() == 1) {
                device = lstDevices.get(0);
            } else {
                GraphicsDevice gdMost = null;
                float maxArea = 0;

                for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstDevices) {
                    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                    Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

                    Rectangle2D intBounds = bounds.createIntersection(parentBounds);
                    float perArea = (float) ((intBounds.getWidth() * intBounds.getHeight()) / (parentBounds.width * parentBounds.height));
                    if (perArea > maxArea) {
                        maxArea = perArea;
                        gdMost = gd;
                    }
                }
                if (gdMost != null) {
                    device = gdMost;
                }
            }
        }

        return device;
    }

}
```

Comment: I looked at your code and truth be told I don't understand much of Graphics Environment but I did find this out: 1. from what I see in the picture you added, the frame still appears above the dock 2. if I change the frame to be `undecorated` then the frame can appear next and behind the dock just by setting its location. So, do you think that OSX limits the bounds of decorated frames to be above the dock? Sorry its hard for me to understand Graphics as I am new to this. Either way your answer was complete and helped me understand a lot so I am accepting it.